# how to change url with textbox value

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a site, e.g., http://www.example.com/
I want to add a search box for searching the addresses etc. like " south dakota " and then click on submit button, and records will be fetch from database in php (Configured mySQL with select query) coded file. I want to show my result on http://www.example.com/south-dakota/ this url. So I want to change url with textbox value and related records will display on that page.

For example you can check this site findbankrates.com

Comment: So which part are you stuck on?

Comment: How can I do this?....
For example findbankrates.com you can check this.... after searching a Bank like bank of America...

Comment: @user1471909 : What if I search letter A and got so many results? so many pages should get opened?

Comment: @FahimParkar  i am talking about url buddy if u search a then the url is  http://www.findbankrates.com/banks/a/

Answer (score 1):

You could set the text field in an HTML form that uses a GET action. Then use a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file that turns www.xyz.com/search.php?string=south%20dakota to www.xyz.com/south%20dakota.

Answer (score 0):

redirect the url using header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/'.variableformtextbox )

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at mod_rewrite to do that... then simply submit the form to that url.

**EDIT:** Linkie:  [URL Rewriting](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html)